# What is the semantic inference or meaning of the term "Calli"?

Tags: c#, il, opcode, opcodes

I have seen this term in various places in code, such as in [graphics programming samples](http://code4k.blogspot.com/2011/03/benchmarking-cnet-direct3d-11-apis-vs.html). It seems to be a C++ semantic, but apparently there is a C# / .NET managed implementation called [EmitCalli](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.emitcalli%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which seems to be related to [OpCodes.Calli](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.calli%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I presume this is a machine language instruction. Is there an explanation of this term that is somewhat close to layman's terms?

Comment: From the description I guess it's an abbreviation for "call indirect".

Comment: No, it's not C++. It's a CIL opcode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means `call indirect` and  it is for the MSIL

> Calls the method indicated on the evaluation stack (as a pointer to an
>   entry point) with arguments described by a calling convention.

In `call`, the method descriptor is passed with the instruction ( and hence direct)

In `calli`, it is given a `method entry pointer` ( and hence indirect)